# Do I need to verify data signed with Nami wallet or will the cryptography algorithms automatically detect if it was tempered with?

Tags: blockchain, nami-wallet, message-signing

Based on this [answer](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/2527/7215) which seems to have some bugs in the verification methods I created this piece of code:

```
const {
  Address,
  Ed25519Signature,
  PublicKey,
  BaseAddress,
  StakeCredential,
  RewardAddress,
} = require("@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs");
const { Buffer } = require("buffer");
const { COSESign1, Label } = require("@emurgo/cardano-message-signing-nodejs");
​
class SignedData {
  constructor(signedDataInHex) {
    let message = COSESign1.from_bytes(
      Buffer.from(Buffer.from(signedDataInHex, "hex"), "hex")
    );
    let headermap = message.headers().protected().deserialized_headers();
    this.headers = {
      algorithmId: headermap.algorithm_id().as_int().as_i32(),
      address: Address.from_bytes(
        headermap.header(Label.new_text("address")).as_bytes()
      ),
      publicKey: PublicKey.from_bytes(headermap.key_id()),
    };
    this.payload = message.payload();
​
    this.signature = Ed25519Signature.from_bytes(message.signature());
    this.data = message.signed_data().to_bytes();
  }
​
  extractData() {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    const payloadString = decoder.decode(this.payload);
    const payloadObj = JSON.parse(payloadString);
    const signerAddress = this.headers.address.to_bech32();
    return { payloadObj, signerAddress };
  }
}
​
let signedDataBytes =
  "845869a30127045820b0999904bd50dfd74835576573d684a1377879278264b55cf83e6201e7975e9c6761646472657373583901655e5688424b3d2f69a9628af9b60be62376cdcd0d10ad9a618999ac4d04421e9d573a5a33a0ac52ea00213c5634e0ca1f1e62a065905356a166686173686564f4581a7b227369676e65644174223a313635353036313038313830397d5840af4a4bb4c7c7ac23c86d6527f797fdd2f058f71d434a1b34ae91abd6fecb504d82e519ace7c171e1238c4aa5bcd252166a58f2ba855770ce98a9123917ded60b";
let signedData = new SignedData(signedDataBytes);
​
console.log(signedData.extractData());
```

Can I safely rely on the data extracted with `extractData()` function? If I managed to extract signer address and payload form the signed data, is it enough to be sure that the signed data was actually signed by the extracted address and that the payload was not tempered with or should I mare some further steps?